# O que significa cardinalidade nesse caso ? (jQuery InputMask)

Tags: jquery, plugin

Tenho o seguinte trecho:

```
$('#elemento').inputmask({
    mask: "*{1,255}",
    greedy: false,
    definitions: {
        '*': {
                 validator: "[A-Za-záãâÁÂÃéêẽÈÊẼìîĩÌÎĨòôõÒÔÕùûũÚÛŨ ]",
                 cardinality: 1
             }
        }
});
```

A pergunta é simples:

> O que significa `'cardinality: 1'` ?

Plugin: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

Comment: Conforme está no link: "
Cardinality especifica quantos caracteres são representados e validados para a definição"

Comment: @Everson isso sim, mas eu não entendi o que isso significa exatamente kk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo a documentação no github a *cardinality* (Cardinalidade) define quantos caracteres representam a definição a ser validada.

No seu exemplo, o caractere `'*'` representa 1 caractere que vai ser validado com a regex: `[A-Za-záãâÁÂÃéêẽÈÊẼìîĩÌÎĨòôõÒÔÕùûũÚÛŨ ]`

Exemplo

```js
$('#elemento1').inputmask({
    mask: "*{1,255}",
    greedy: false,
    definitions: {
       '*': {
           validator: "[A-Za-záãâÁÂÃéêẽÈÊẼìîĩÌÎĨòôõÒÔÕùûũÚÛŨ ]",
           cardinality: 1
       }
    }
});

$('#elemento2').inputmask({
    mask: "*{1,255}",
    greedy: false,
    definitions: {
       '*': {
           validator: "[A-Za-záãâÁÂÃéêẽÈÊẼìîĩÌÎĨòôõÒÔÕùûũÚÛŨ ]",
           cardinality: 2
       }
    }
});

$('#elemento3').inputmask({
    mask: "*{1,255}",
    greedy: false,
    definitions: {
       '*': {
           validator: "[A-Za-záãâÁÂÃéêẽÈÊẼìîĩÌÎĨòôõÒÔÕùûũÚÛŨ ]",
           cardinality: 3
       }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/4.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="elemento1" />

<p/>
<input type="text" id="elemento2" />

<p/>
<input type="text" id="elemento3" />
```